# Java How to extract a complete XML block with xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have XML files like this:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      <id>0</id>
    </C>
  </B>
  <B>
    <C>
      <id>1</id>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

And I would like to get B block when C has a specific id. For example, if I want to get the block with id=1, I want this reponse:

```
      <B>
        <C>
          <id>1</id>
        </C>
      </B>
```

But I do not know how can I get the part I want. I tried:

```
Node result = (Node)xPath.evaluate("A/B/C[id = '1']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

But returns an C block, when I want B block.

And:

```
Node result = (Node)xPath.evaluate("B[A/B/C[id = '1']]", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

returns null.

Also I have read the official documentation but I did not find anything:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks.

Comment: Do `result.getParent()` with first try, it will give you the B of the C you want ;)

Comment: Thank you! Also it works

Comment: I've add it in answer, you can accept it if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predicates simply mean "only keep this element if it respects the condition I put in this predicate"

So simply,

```
A/B[C/id = 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **parent** axes in xpath query.
As you mentioned, you want to get B block when C has a specific id.
You have to query with **parent** axes just like

**//*[id="1"]/parent::B**

Here is detail s of the command.

> **//*** is the nested-path till xpath finds id.
>
> ***[id="1"]*** is condition according to you requirement.
>
> **/parent::B** will return parents node from id tag to B tag including B.

[Demo of the Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NTFc.png)

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node result = ((Node)xPath.evaluate("A/B/C[id = '1']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE))
                                                                  .getParent();
```

This is the solution with the Java method, get a C element, and then take its parent

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to extract a block of text with vtd-xml.. and XPath. The key is using getElementFragment, which returns the offset and length of a fragment in the source XML document.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws VTDException{
    String xml="<A>"+
      "<B>\n"+
        "<C>\n"+
          "<id>0</id>\n"+
        "</C>\n"+
      "</B>\n"+
      "<B>\n"+
        "<C>\n"+
          "<id>1</id>\n"+
        "</C>\n"+
      "</B>\n"+
    "</A>\n";
    VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
    vg.setDoc(xml.getBytes());
    vg.parse(false);
    VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
    AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
    ap.selectXPath("/A/B[C/id='1']");
    System.out.println("====>"+ap.getExprString());
    int i=0,count=0;
    System.out.println(" token count ====> "+ vn.getTokenCount() );
    while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
        long l = vn.getElementFragment();
        System.out.println("fragment content ====>"+ 
                new String(vn.getXML().getBytes(),(int)l,(int)(l>>32)));
    }
    System.out.println(" count ===> "+count);
}
```